# Bash script to install specific package from ubuntu (if exists)

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Let's say that i want to install specific package from ubuntu repos, but all depends of codename. For example, on ubuntu 14.04 lts there is a package called librabbitmq1, and on ubuntu 16.04 librabbitmq4. Depends on codename i want to choose existing one.

```
"If ubuntu_codename=trusty install librabbitmq1 
   else 
install librabbitmq4"
```

or something like this...

```
"If apt-get install librabbitmq1 returns 1 (or positive) install that, else install librabbitmq4"
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple one-liner in `bash` could do the trick which works on the return-code(s) of the commands executed.

```
sudo apt-get install librabbitmq1  || echo "librabbitmq1 Installation failed" && sudo apt-get install librabbitmq4  || echo "librabbitmq4  Installation failed"
```